# do assertations exist in both JAVA and JUnit?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, webdriver, assert

I am looking at one of the question that is posted long back by x person.

Ex: assertEquals(driver.getPageSource().contains("sometext"), true);

(or) assertEquals(boolean , boolean);

If the above method exists I love to use it. I looked around JUnit API and its methods and there is no such method  .

1) If it exists can someone post the relevant link, please ?

2) do assertations exist in JAVA default classes?  (I know they are there in JUNIT)

Comment: These are two separate (and unrelated) questions; please post them as two separate posts...

Comment: What happens when you try to use assertEquals(boolean,boolean)? Is ther any error? or unexpected behavior? 
Another thing is better use assertTrue(boolean condition), for these kind of boolean checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertEquals methods are in `JUnit`, specifically in the `org.junit.Assert` class:

You typically import them with a static import statement like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

`assert` on its own is part of core Java, it provides a way to add sanity checks that get run while you are debugging, but which get ignored (and therefore don't add any overhead) in production code.

```
assert(something==somethingElse);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("sometext"));`?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do assertions in your main Java code (say for a sanity check), you can use the [`assert` keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html). Methods like [`assertTrue()` and `assertEquals()`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) from JUnit are meant to be used in JUnit-based unit testing code.

Answer (score 3):

The most basic example is the one @daniel-kaplan suggested but if you have an option of adding additional lib in your testing scope i would suggest [Hamcrest matchers](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial). They add super awesome syntax sugar.

You example would be:

```
assertThat(driver.getPageSource(), containsString("someText"));
```

Answer (score 0):

API documentation generated with javadoc. [JUnit javadoc link](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/)

If you want to use the method to compare beteewn boolean and boolean,
maybe you can use the method assertTrue(boolean condition) .

java code:

```
 assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("sometext"));
```